# JavaScript variable when sending data via jQuery $.post() function

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem when I want to send input data via jQuery's `$.post`. I have this input:

```
<input id="mydata" value='<?php echo $data; ?>' >
```

and I want to send its data via jQuery's `$.post()` function.

This `$.post` function runs, but it does't send anything:

```
var the_data = $('#mydata').val();
//alert(the_data); has correct data!!
$.post("http://php/server", the_data , function(data){
    alert(data);
}, "html");
```

But this one sends data correctly:

```
$.post("http://php/server", <?php echo $data; ?> , function(data){}, "html");
```

I should use input for saving data and method 2 isn't suitable for me.

Comment: What type of input is it? Text, Password, Radio, etc?

Comment: type is hidden, but data is text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data needs to be an object.

```
var the_data = {
    mydata: $('#mydata').val()
};
```

You can access this in your PHP with `$_POST['mydata']`.

Comment: thanks! but a minor error: ...val() has no ";". thanks again!